# If condition satisfies execute function otherwise check again after some time : Python

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am developing a web project:

1. Some user generated data comes to server.
2. Async Task

   ```
   def (data):
       if data satisfies condition:
           #execute rest of the code
       else:
           # try again after sometime.
   ```
3. Is there a way to do this without using cron job, the interval in which the re-check happens can be static too.

Comment: You may look into `celery` package.

Comment: i am aware of that, is there a way using which we can achieve this, like before executing a task checks for a condition and if not then check again after some time.

Comment: Have you looked into the possibility of using a signal ? You can use this if the user generated content, lets say updates the database